# Localization 3rd party frameworks, UIView etc

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle

How to make localization for 3rd party frameworks, specially for custom `UIView's`.
To make localization for a project is pretty simple, you just need to add Localization.strings, but how to make localization for custom `UIView` in separate file. And when you add you custom `UIView` to project you don't need to copy/paste localization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The best way to make localization for your own frameworks or custom UI](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/05/resource-bundles/)

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/